# io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerStream deframeFailed

Tags: java, grpc

I use grpc-java for server and android, ios for client .But i always get below exception untimed, what can i do for this, and is it serious？Thanks.

```
io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerStream deframeFailed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: MessageDeframer is already closed
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.checkNotClosed(MessageDeframer.java:222)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.deframe(MessageDeframer.java:168)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream.deframe(AbstractStream.java:276)
```

Comment: That looks like a bug. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1569), but I think you may be hitting a different issue. Did you see this log on the server-side? How frequently do you see it, are there other messages, and could you provide a fuller stack trace?

Comment: It's a server-side exception.the full stack trace is too long to add to here.

Comment: Please file an issue then, and include the stack trace.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46873056/5330223